# QT - Where is config.ini

Tags: qt, config, ini, qsettings

I wanted to save db's conenction in `Config.ini` file. I created it and added to project (as "other file") - suitable record appered in `.pro` file.

I started in code with this:

```
QSettings settings(QDir::currentPath()+"/"+fileName, QSettings::IniFormat);
```

Then i created 2 functions

1. for savng settings:

   ```
   settings.beginGroup("DB");
       settings.setValue("HostName",_hostName); 
       //_hostName is attribute I can access, so that's not an issue
   settings.endGroup();
   ```
2. for reading settings

   ```
   settings.beginGroup("DBSettings");
       _hostName =settings.value("HostName", "Unknown").toString();
       // hostName  is attribute i can access
   settings.endGroup();
   ```

I initially called 1. and then 2.

It seems like that the `.ini` file is created and I could read from it, but it's not that I added to project and i can't find it in the folder it supposed to be.

It works, but I need to include it into the project and I need to be able to "control" it.

Comment: Have you checked the build folder? By default, Qt Creator doesn't run applications from the project folder.

Comment: As @MrEricSir suggest, you can check in whic dir you're running the code with `QDir::currentPath()`

Comment: Yes i did - that's why i'm confused - it wasnt saved in any directory - i even used "find" to look for it, but nothing, no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem myself. Turned out, that line :

```
QSettings settings(QDir::currentPath()+"/"+fileName, QSettings::IniFormat);
```

just has to be repalced with

```
settings = new QSettings(QDir::currentPath()+"/"+fileName, QSettings::IniFormat);
```